# Smooth loading of videos in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been trying to add some videos into my tableView using the AVPlayer which I placed into the TableView Cell.

But the UI freezes while the video is being loaded.

This is my cellforRow at indexpath.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCel {


    var tableCell : UITableViewCell? = nil

    if (tableCell == nil){

        tableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    let view = tableCell?.viewWithTag(9999)
    tableCell?.tag = indexPath.row


    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         if (tableCell?.tag == indexPath.row){
                let player = self.cache.object(forKey: indexPath.row as AnyObject) as! AVPlayer
                let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                playerLayer.frame = (view?.bounds)!
                view?.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                player.play()

            }

//            tableView.reloadData()
    }

 return tableCell!
}
```

This is how I added the videos to the cache.

```
    for i in 0...10{

        var videoURL : URL? = nil

        if (i%2 == 0){

            videoURL = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
        }else{

            videoURL = URL(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")

        }
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)

        arr?.append(player)

        self.cache.setObject(player, forKey: i as AnyObject)
        print("count = \(arr?.count)")
    }
```

What would be the best method to have this resolved?

Comment: how did you solve it ?

Comment: @FaridAlHaddad I had a design change and this portion was taken off. Int he new design I had to navigate to a new page and then show the  video from there.

Comment: Oh okay .. thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, you're in luck. iOS is optimized for just these types of issues. Apple engineers have gone to great lengths to provide APIs to help you achieve buttery smooth scrolling *and* load your content at the same time.

> **Note**: Solving this issue *requires* offloading tasks to different  threads on the CPU. It can get complicated, and there's a lot to learn about it. I *strongly* recommend you read Apple's documentation.

First, know that the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method *should* generally call your data source on the main thread. Meaning the call you have to `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not appropriately used in this scenario.

Instead, what you'll need to do is offload your `AVPlayer` caching to a separate, background thread and then come back into the main thread to **update** the cell's layer content. Additionally, you shouldn't be doing that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You'll likely need to subclass a `UITableViewCell` and write your own loading sequence within that - that way, you can quickly `init` your custom cell, hand it back to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (which can then continue along merrily), and keep loading things and updating from within the cell subclass.

To setup your AVPlayer in a background thread, do this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    // Background thread
    // Do your AVPlayer work here

    // When you need to update the UI, switch back out to the main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Main thread
        // Do your UI updates here
    }
}
```

You may want to look at the quality of service value you pass in when you create your background thread. The `userInitiated` QOS may be better for this specific case because the videos are being loaded as a result of a user-initiated action.

As for the actual caching of the videos. I am not *too* familiar with `AVPlayer` or `AVPlayerItem`, but from my understanding the more metadata (i.e. duration, tracks, etc.) you can give to `AVPlayer` before trying to render the video in a layer, the faster it goes (see this related [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30376386/814730)).

Additionally, you'll probably want to check out the newly introduced APIs in iOS 10 that all you to **pre-fetch** cells in a table view. If you take advantage of the pre-fetch optimizations, you could likely load everything you need for `AVPlayer` in the background and well before the cells are ever requested for display in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Anyhow, hope you can get started from there and solve the issue. Definitely take the time to read the documentation on `AVKit`, `GCD`, and `UITableView` (specifically the new pre-fetching APIs).

Comment: Thank you Samuel, I can see that there is a huge performance improvement in the tableCell scrolling. I believe I may need to do some tinkering in the caching part too.

Comment: In case of fast scrolling, the TableView cell may go out of user's view while the background thread may still be executing. If I am doing a `DispatchQueue.global` from within the `UITableViewCell` subclass, how am I supposed to know when the cell is being dequeued so as to cancel the Async process? any Idea? Otherwise it could become a memory leak case....