# AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL a little slow to have a very good smoth scrolling

Tags: ios, performance, avplayer, avplayeritem

During the scrolling of my app feed, I load some videos inside an AVPlayer. The problem is that `AVPlayerItem playerItemWithUrl` and `AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem` are a little slow (around 16ms), so it's produce frame drop in my app. Is their any way to speed it up? Maybe i can call these functions in a background thread ?

Below the code i use to create the Player:

```
  FPlayerItem := TAVPlayerItem.Wrap(TAVPlayerItem.OCClass.playerItemWithURL(aURL)); 
  FPlayer := TAVPlayer.Wrap(TAVPlayer.OCClass.playerWithPlayerItem(FPlayerItem));
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have used to play the item ?

Comment: It's will be probably irrelevant because it's made in delphi, but i simply do AVPlayerItem playerItemWithUrl and later AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem nothing else

Comment: Did you try playing the item inside loadValuesAsynchronously ?

Comment: i update the question with the code. no, how to use loadValuesAsynchronously ?

Answer (score 1):

Play the item inside [**AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronouskeyvalueloading).
It clearly states :

> Methods you can implement to use an asset or asset track without
>   blocking the calling thread.

So logically, for understanding:

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
let keys: [String] = ["playable"]
asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys) {
DispatchQueue.main.async {         
      let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
      let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
      player.play()
      }
}
```

[**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363502/maintaining-good-scroll-performance-when-using-avplayer) will help you understand it better.